# How to set data from a react hook inside of a function or event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn to create hooks so I can re-use data that I have to change in different components.

I'm using [Material UI's Tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/) and need to use useTab, a custom hook to change the tab id.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ProductsContext } from './ProductsContext';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import { useTab } from '../../hooks/tab';

const ProductsNav = () => {
    const {products, categories, loading} = useContext(ProductsContext);
    const [tabValue] = useTab(0);

    const handleTabChange = (e, newTabValue) => {
        useTab(newTabValue);
    }

    return (
        <div className="products">
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={ handleTabChange }>
                    {
                        Array.from(categories).map(category => (
                            !category.unlisted && (<Tab label={category.title} key={category.id}/>)
                        ))
                    }
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>

        </div>
    ); 
};

export default ProductsNav;
```

I know it does this with child functions in the docs, but I'm trying to not just copy and paste and do it in my own way.

Here is my custom useTab hook:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const useTab = (selectedTab) => {
    const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTabValue(selectedTab);
    }, []);
    return [tabValue];
}
```

I'm of course getting an error I can't use a hook inside of a function, but I'm confused how else to do this.

How can I change tabValue from useTabs?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably here:

```
const handleTabChange = (e, newTabValue) => {
    useTab(newTabValue);
}
```

You're violating one of the primary [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
>   Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.

The reason for this rule is a bit complex but it basically boils down to the idea that hooks should *only* be called at the top level of a React functional component because they must be *guaranteed* to run every time the component function is run.

Hence why you're getting an error "I can't use a hook inside of a function"...

At any rate, it is unclear why you are using a custom hook with a `useEffect()` here. That seems completely unnecessary - a regular `useEffect()` hook inside of your nav component should more than suffice:

```
const ProductsNav = () => {
    const {products, categories, loading} = useContext(ProductsContext);
    const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0);

    const handleTabChange = (e, newTabValue) => {
        setTabValue(newTabValue);
    }

    return (
        <div className="products">
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={ handleTabChange }>
                    {
                        Array.from(categories).map(category => (
                            !category.unlisted && (<Tab label={category.title} key={category.id}/>)
                        ))
                    }
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>

        </div>
    ); 
};
```

Comment: Hi I'm using a custom hook so I can use TabPane in another component....

Comment: @kinx In that case you should simply move your `tabValue` state up a few levels in your component hierarchy so that you can make it available (pass it down as props) to multiple components. This concept is called "lifting up state" and understanding it is critical to how you manage state in your React app. It has nothing to do with hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html